# How to use a string array as a txt file name in fopen in C

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

I've been working on a program and I need to read a .txt file.
However the name of the file to be opened must be specified by the user:

```
#include stdio.h    

int main(void) {
    char FN[30];

    FILE *Fptr;

    printf("%s","Enter the full path of the file you wish to open.\n");
    scanf("%s",FN);
    if ((Fptr=fopen(FN,"r+"))==NULL) {
        printf("%s","File could not be opened.\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s","File opened successfully.\n");
    }
}
```

I repeatedly get the message "File could not be opened."
I think the problem must be somehow in the array I use as the file name, because when I tried:

```
if ((Fptr=fopen("/Volumes/NO NAME/IntroProgramming/Version-0/test.txt","r+"))==NULL)
```

instead of:

```
if ((Fptr=fopen(FN,"r+"))==NULL)
```

the program works just fine.

Comment: Do you know what the `30` in `char FN[30];` means?

Comment: juan says that your buffer is to small. your example path has 53 length

Comment: The error message is not very useful. Try: `if ((Fptr=fopen(FN,"r+"))==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"File \"%s\"could not be opened.\n", FN);`

Comment: Also, `if ((Fptr=fopen(/Volumes/NO NAME/IntroProgramming/Version-0/test.txt,"r+"))==NULL` won't compile. It should've been `if ((Fptr=fopen("/Volumes/NO NAME/IntroProgramming/Version-0/test.txt","r+"))==NULL`

Comment: Please don't retype code. Copy and paste instead. The line you are saying "works just fine" can't possibly compile because it lacks quotes. Nobody has a slightest idea about other ways your posted code subtly differs from what you are really trying to run. Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: If your file name contains spaces, `scanf` won't read it. Use some other function like `fgets`.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, the file name (which should be used enclosed in "") has more then the 30 char you have allocated for the `FN` variable and contains a space too. In order to read that string from stdin you can use something like this:

```
char FN[129];

if ( scanf("%128[^\n] ", FN) != 1 ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"No string was read from stdin.\n");
}
```